# sendemail with gmail says connection refused

Tags: gmail, smtp

I am trying to send an rmail with sendemail. installed via macports. What is wrong in the following and how do I go about fixing it?

```
bash-3.2$ sendemail -f username@gmail.com -u files -m message -t username@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com -a ~/temp/folder/*pdf
Jan 31 01:49:43 mycomp sendemail[10391]: ERROR => Connection attempt to smtp.gmail.com:25 failed: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail wont accept connection without TLS support and the specific port `587` for it. [Read it here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287). Execute the following -

> sendemail -f username@gmail.com -u files -m message -t username@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -o tls=yes -a ~/temp/folder/*pdf

If this doesn't work, then provide your SMTP username and password with `-xu` and `-xp` options respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and could resolve it. You can use the tls auto, 587 port command. Able to successfully send an email using Gmail SMTP.

```
sendemail -f "mymail@gmail.com" -u "Re : Alerts Script" -t "$EMAILS" -s "smtp.gmail.com:587" -o tls=auto -xu "mymail@gmail.com" -xp "Password" -m "$Msg"
```

Also, you have to apply couple of settings in Gmail.

1. Enable IMAP
2. Allow less secure app
3. Review suspicious activity and mark 'That's me' to allow communication.